# URL to display a Visualforce page in salesforce1

Tags: salesforce

How to display a Visualforce page in Salesforce1 without using a tab. What is the URL to be provided in the href attribute?

The following do not work:

/apex/VF_Pagename
{!URLFOR($Page.VF_Pagename)}

Using the above URLs styles the page more like a browser. I want the header bar of salesforce1 visible.

Answer (score 0):

Since Salesforce1 doesn't support the /apex/Page style of redirecting to VF Pages, I think you'll want to consider using custom Publisher Actions to surface your VF Page. These can either be at the record level or the global level.

http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=actions_overview.htm

Answer (score 0):

Visualforce pages can surface in Salesforce1 as:

++ Tab in the Navigation Menu

++ Mobile card in a record view

++ A mobile card in the related information page

++ In a publisher action layout

If you're worried about styling a custom VF page, consider using the styling from the Mobile Design Templates: https://developer.salesforce.com/en/mobile/services/mobile-templates/templates-faq.